# Substrate dependency management

Tags: substrate-node-template, packages

My team is looking to implement a project in Substrate, and after some studying it seems like a dependency management nightmare.

Many of the 'sp' libraries call specific required functions within our own maintained codebase.

Has anyone come up with a system to manage the updates to substrate core packages in a semi-automated fashion?

Answer (score 8):

Polkadot is the number one "user" of the Substrate blockchain framework, and handles updates to Substrate without issue. Similarly, all parachain teams are also able to keep things up to date and running.

On the main Polkadot repo, we point all dependencies to the Substrate `master` branch. For example:

```toml
sp-runtime = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "master", default-features = false }
```

Each time we make a PR to the Polkadot repo, we update the Substrate dependencies:

```bash
# this will trigger an update to all Substrate related dependencies
cargo update -p sp-io
```

Somtimes, this does involve a breaking change, but there will always be a [companion PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5112/files) to the Polkadot repo showing how to fix the breaking change. Usually you can use these as a guide on how to update your own project.

When launching a release of your chain, it is best to synchronize with the releases of Polkadot, especially if you plan to be a parachain.

For that, you create a new branch which does not use `master`, but instead one of the [`polkadot-v...`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/branches/all?query=polkadot-v) branches.

Making continuous iterative updates can be better than doing a bunch of updates at once, so as long as you have been keeping up with `master`, it should be pretty easy.

However, some teams choose to build entirely on just the `polkadot-v...` branches, and only upgrade once per release cycle.

All of these processes are easily integrated into all CI pipelines.

Comment: While this is good information, it is missing the fact that many parachains also rely on other repositories using substrate too (we have at least 5 for Moonbeam). Upgrading the dependencies is usually a long (and manual) process to make sure they all work with the new code, but also to ensure the changes are not "impacting" your chain without you noticing it.

Comment: yes, it is not a easy job, as Shawn mentioned, you need to check the upstream pr(substrate/polkadot/cumulus or even 3rd modules like moonbeam you said) one by one to see if it contain any change you should take care

Comment: @Crystalin out of curiosity, what external repositories does Moonbeam rely on? Just looking for guidance on the tooling as well. Are you relying on tests to catch breaking changes from external deps?

Comment: @Crystalin would be very happy to see your version of an answer to this question, given that you are probably solving some problems that we at Parity do not need to solve.